# CodeIgniter, Twig and multilanguage

Tags: php, codeigniter, twig

I got a CodeIgniter based Website - it already got multilang support. Language files are located in application/language and at the moment I use CI Views for output ( `$this->load->view()` ). In the view I currently use `$this->lang->line('forum_submit')` to get the language string.

I want to use a template engine and found Spark/Twiggy as it is a CI-Implementation for Twig (I'm not familiar with Twig and started using it yesterday).

Now my question is how do I realize multilanguage support in / with twig. Is there any workaround for `$this->lang->line()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While writing the question I suddenly found the solution for my problem: When Im not using `$this->lang->line()` in templates anymore but

```
$this->load->helper('language');    
$this->twiggy->register_function('lang');
```

in Controller, I can write `{{ lang("form_submit") }}` in twig.

Amazing! Problem solved.